# Failed to install ssh-0.2.12 (haskell package )

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ssh

I tried to install haskell package ssh-0.2.12 with 
`sudo cabal install ssh-0.2.12` but it fails with

```
src/SSH.hs:58:114: Not in scope: type constructor or class `SHA1'

src/SSH.hs:59:115: Not in scope: type constructor or class `MD5'
Failed to install ssh-0.2.12
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ssh-0.2.12 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
```

I am on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason why you are giving the version number explicitly? What happens with just `cabal install ssh`?

Comment: cabal install ssh returns the same failure message. I mention the version in case I missed any library in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ssh` just depends on `cryptohash` without an uppper version bound.

It was probably written against cryptohash 0.9.1, in which the `MD5` constructor [existed and where it is marked as deprecated](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cryptohash/0.9.1/doc/html/Crypto-Hash-MD5.html), but now cryptohash 0.10.0 is out which [doesn't contain](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cryptohash/0.10.0/doc/html/Crypto-Hash-MD5.html) it anymore.

Your cabal will install the latest versions of dependencies if there are no restrictions on them.

The right thing to do is to file a bug against the `ssh` package so that it gets updated. You can find a bugtracker URL [on its hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ssh).

---

Note: It is [controversial](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ydkcq/pvp_upper_bounds_are_not_our_friends/) whether upper version bounds are good or bad.

Comment: As temporary solution, you can get `ssh` to install by specifying the older version of `cryptohash` explicitly i.e. `cabal install ssh cryptohash-0.9.1`. This works as long as you don't have any other libraries that depend/are linked against the newer `cryptohash`.